# Let $ R = \mathbb{Z}_8$. Find a nonzero polynomial $f$ in $R[x]$ of degree at most 3 such that each element of $R$ is a root of $f$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomial-rings

I tried using the method provided [by Mark here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2211307/r-bbb-z-6-bbb-z-come-up-with-nonzero-polynomial-f-in-rx-of-degree-at-m) but I can't seem to come up with a solution for $\mathbb{Z}_8$.

Comment: Is the polynomial required to be monic?

Comment: @BenGrossmann No, that is not a requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going in the direction of the link you provided, what about $p(x)=4x(x+1)$?

Comment: Yes, this certainly seems to work. What was your motivation for constructing it in this way?

Comment: Either $4x$ or $4(x+1)$ is equal to zero depending on whether $x$ is odd or even.

Comment: @Jeremiah I added an answer explaining why the linked  method doesn't work and, further, how to *discover* the sought polynomial from this faiilure.

Answer (score 0):

The linked method of iterating the Factor Theorem to get multiple factors from various roots works fine in fields (and domains), but generally it fails in non-domains like $\,\Bbb Z_8,\,$ where $\,4\cdot 2 = 0.\,$ Indeed, as explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/677084/242) we can deduce that $\,f(a) = 0 = f(b)$ $\Rightarrow f(x) = (x-a)(x-b)g(x)\,$ only when $\,a-b\,$ is *cancellable*.

Let's see how it breaks. $\,f(0) = 0\,\Rightarrow\, f = x\, g.\,$ $\,0 = f(1) = 1\cdot g(1)\, $ so $\, g= (x\!-\!1)h,\,$ so $\,f = x(x\!-\!1)h.\,$ $\,0 = f(2) = 2(1)h(2),\,$ but we can't conclude $\,h(2)=0\,$ because $2$ is not cancellable in $\,\Bbb Z_8$. But we can infer $\,8\mid 2h(2)\,\Rightarrow\,4\mid h(2).\,$ Taking $\,h = 4\,$ does the job, i.e. $\,8\mid 4x(x\!-\!1)\,$ by $\,2\mid x(x\!-\!1),\,$ for all $\,x.$